# Mysql query took long time to execute

Tags: mysql

The following is my query to get the information from various tables.

I am using mysql database.

```
 $sql="select c.cid,c.id,c.compid, c.firstname,c.lastname,c.phone,c.home_phone,c.payment,c.status,c.pstatus, c.pstatus2, c.reservation, u.triptype,u.flight_type_arr, u.flight_type_dep, c.email,c.sugg_pickup_date_time,c.sugg_airport_pickup_time,u.triptype,u.traveltype,            
            dr_arr.driver_name as driver_name_arr, dr_arr.driver_email as driver_email_arr, 
            dr_dep.driver_name as driver_name_dep, dr_dep.driver_email as driver_email_dep,
            ar.rid,ar.finalprice1, ar.finalprice2, ap.p1, ap.p2, ap.p3, ap.transaction_id
            from customer c
            left join vehicle_fees vf1 on (vf1.vehicle_id=c.vehicle_id1)
            left join vehicle_fees vf2 on (vf2.vehicle_id=c.vehicle_id2)
            left join userinfo u on (u.id=c.id)
            left join holiday_fees hf1 on (hf1.holidayfee_Date=u.date)
            left join holiday_fees hf2 on (hf2.holidayfee_Date=u.date1)
            left join airport_reservation ar on (ar.cid = c.cid)
            left join driver dr_arr on (dr_arr.did = ar.did_arr)
            left join driver dr_dep on (dr_dep.did = ar.did_dep)
            left join airport_payment ap on (ap.cid = c.cid)
            where (c.reservation = 'booked' or c.reservation = 'cancelled') ORDER BY c.cid DESC" .$var_limit;
```

But It is taking more time to execute.

Can anybody suggest whether my query is wrong or correct?

Comment: Show us 'explain select' output.

Comment: It is very normal to have this query slow! It uses 10 joins.. I am sure some (all?!) tables doesn't have indices. To help you better, you should give us tables structures and declared indices.

Answer (score 1):

When doing like you have -- a primary table (Customers) is being joined to all the other "optional" tables, sometimes I've found that MySQL tries to think for you and internally restructure what IT considers is the primary table.  By using a known special keyword MIGHT help..

```
from: 
    SELECT (rest of query)
to:
    SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN (rest of query)
```

Now, for your where clause and order by.  Ensure you have an index on (reservation, cid)

Answer (score 0):

The query looks legit, the problem that I see is that it has no limits. Usually you should put a LIMIT statement in the end of the query script to limit the amount of rows you want to get. I wonder how many records is there.

Comment: No, you can't say "the query looks legit" without more information. Just because it has no syntax errors doesn't make it legit. And a `LIMIT` does not magically fix problems.

Comment: Well this guy, doesn't get any errors, it just loads slowly, this means that he is having optimization problems, such as too much data

Comment: Yes, and he **is** asking for **optimization**, and just putting a `LIMIT` is not really optimization. So your point is actually useless.

Comment: You are a troll, you didn't gave any assistance at all, why do you fight with me if I had given a good advice, which might suffice his requirements.

Comment: Because it's not possible with the information given. Seeing that there is already an answer which also has an upvote, might prevent others to even have a look at the question. So actually your post is more harmful to the OP as anything else.

Comment: The OP's query already seems to have a `LIMIT` clause, but it's in a `$var_limit` at the end.